# Testing Async Action with lambda chaining

Tags: redux, jestjs, redux-thunk

I am learning how to unit test a simple action creator as seen below and want to find out the best way to test it.  I've been going off an example from the redux docs on writing tests but wonder if it is possible to test async actions with lambda chaining.

Action:

```
export const toggleSelect = (id, key) => dispatch => {
  return dispatch({
    type: TOGGLE_LIST_ITEM,
    payload: { id, key },
  });
};
```

Test (jest)

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as actions from '../';
import * as types from '../types';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);
describe('list actions', () => {
  it('should create an action to unselect all list items', () => {
    const id = '123';
    const key = 'selectedProspects';
    const expectedAction = {
      type: types.UNSELECT_ALL_OF_TYPE,
      key,
    };

    const store = mockStore();

    return actions.toggleSelect(id, key).then(() => {
      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedAction);
    });
  });
});
```

does anyone know of a good way to test this?  I am not sure if this not working being indicative to writing more testable code, or if I am just missing something.

Comment: That test won't work as-is, for two reasons: 1) you're not _dispatching_ the `toggleSelect()` action, and 2) `toggleSelect()` is not a thunk and doesn't return a promise.

Comment: The first part makes sense.  I think wrapping in `store.dispatch()` should fix the first item you mentinoed.  But what about the action isn't a thunk?   I thought it was just a function that returns a dispatched action

Comment: No, a thunk is an action creator that returns a second function.  Your `toggleSelect()` is a simple action creator that returns an action object.  See https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk and https://daveceddia.com/what-is-a-thunk/ .

Comment: Er... wait, my bad. I seem to have misread your `toggleSelect()` function.  It _is_ a thunk.  However, it's definitely not returning a promise.  As written right now, it doesn't even need to be a thunk at all, just a simple action creator returning an object.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, you just need to make use of dispatch:

```
const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);
describe('list actions', () => {
  it('should create an action to unselect all list items', () => {
    const id = '123';
    const key = 'selectedProspects';
    const expectedAction = {
      type: types.UNSELECT_ALL_OF_TYPE,
      key,
    };

    const store = mockStore();

    return store.dispatch(actions.toggleSelect(id, key)).then(() => {
      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedAction);
    });
  });
});
```

Your action itself doesn't need to be a thunk. You could easily write that as an action creator... i.e.

```
export function toggleSelect(id, key) {
    return {
        type: TOGGLE_LIST_ITEM,
        payload: { id, key },
    };
}
```